# Imprimir en el PC del cliente que esta visualizando una web PHP

Tags: php, impresión

Estoy desarrollando un gestor de colas "pequeño" que será utilizado por distintas oficinas de una provincia y estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de imprimir el ticket con el turno solicitado por el usuario. El caso es que el gestor desarrollado estará alojado en un servidor y debe poder utilizarse en distintas oficinas, cada una de ellas con una impresora de tickets distinta. Yo puedo imprimir desde mi proyecto en local en la impresora de tickets seleccionada (metiéndola en dominio y agregándola al servidor) pero claro, no quiero tener que agregar al servidor de producción cada una de las impresoras alojadas por las distintas oficinas...tenéis algún tipo de idea?. 
Os dejo aquí la función de impresión del ticket:

```
function impresion($turno)
{   
    //$handle = printer_open(); //Toma por defecto la impresora asignada al servidor
    $handle = printer_open(IMPRESORA);
    printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
    printer_start_page($handle);
    // create content here
    $font = printer_create_font("Arial",  288, 36, 400, false, false, false, 0);
    $font1 = printer_create_font("Arial",  72, 36, 400, false, false, false, 0);
    $font2 = printer_create_font("Arial",  48, 9, 400, false, false, false, 0);

    printer_select_font($handle, $font1);
    //printer_draw_text($handle, "Su turno ", 1, 225);
    // get image height, width
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize(PATHINCLUDE_GTURNOS."img/"."cabecera1_acceso.bmp");
    printer_draw_bmp($handle, PATHINCLUDE_GTURNOS."img/"."cabecera1_acceso.bmp", 20, 1,500,$height*2);

    printer_select_font($handle, $font);
    //  printer_draw_text($handle, $turno, 200, 290); //SI METO LA PALABRA "SU TURNO" PONER ESTAS MEDIDAS
    printer_draw_text($handle, $turno, 215, 220);
    printer_delete_font($font);

    printer_select_font($handle, $font2);
    printer_draw_text($handle, "Fecha: " . date('d/m/Y'), 20, 560);
    printer_draw_text($handle, "Hora: " . date('H:i:s'), 390, 560);
    //  printer_draw_text($handle, "Fecha: " . date('d/m/Y'), 1, 600); ***SI METO LA PALABRA "SU TURNO" PONER ESTAS MEDIDAS***
    //  printer_draw_text($handle, "Hora: " . date('H:i:s'), 230, 600);

    //printer_delete_font($font);

    printer_end_page($handle);
    printer_end_doc($handle);
    printer_close($handle);
}
```

La definición de la impresora es la siguiente:  define(IMPRESORA,"\\servidor2\i(CAE001)");

También he pensado en la posiblidad de crear un servidor de impresión, nunca he desarrollado ninguno...¿me lo recomendáis?

Comment: tal como lo tienes, eso seria un fallo de seguridad, pues estarias accediendo a la impresora de un cliente, cuando la aplicacion REALMENTE esta en el servidor (por eso puedes acceder a la impresora de tu equipo). Esto se suele hacer generando una vista en html, y luego lanzando el visor de impresion del cliente con javascript. tambien puede que haya mas maneras